# Any advantage or disadvantage to using the command line vs the graphical update process using update manager?

Tags: command-line, upgrade, update-manager

11.10 to 12.04 Upgrade: My natural inclination is to go for the command line update method using:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Any advantage or disadvantage to using the command line vs the graphical update process using update manager? Ubuntu's website recommends using update manager but I suspect this may be due to many user's aversion to using the command line.

Comment: I think suggesting command line method for upgrading  to normal users will make a negative impact '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both run the same commands under the hood, so you will end up with the same upgrade either way.

The main advantage of the command-line method is that it makes it easier to see any errors/warnings that might occur, so power-users can quickly fix them.  The downside of that is that the specific errors are often confusing/scary, and the GUI method does a much better job of explaining things and how to fix them. The GUI method should be recommended for most people, especially new users.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, both should do the same thing. only thing is graphical method is more suitable for people who are new or don't play with CLI much.